# Using abbreviations for key names in document DBs

Tags: database, database-design

Document DBs don't provide optimization for key compression of in documents. Usually the documents in a buckets has the same key set.

So instead of having the following schema for some bucket:

```
user = {
 name: "Joe Kminski",
 birthDate: "2000-01-01",
 location: "Argentina, Sao Paulo", ... }
```

We can have:

```
user = {
 n: "Joe Kminski",
 birD: "2000-01-01",
 loc: "Argentina, Sao Paulo", ... }
```

The motivation is to fit more documents in a cache.
The pros for full names is more readable code from start. All in all at the end we have a printed version of DB schema.

**Is it worth to go with short names? Did you encounter any problems with them?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Right, it wasn't clear. I've just updated.

Comment: There is a trade-off here.  If you can as a developer fit more columns in the structure, it becomes more obfuscated for folks that tie into your database.  However, you can fit more data into the result set.  It kind of falls into the same line as normalization..  How much do you want to do before it becomes over-normalized?  :)